# Typescript validation rules for variables with and without explicit types

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion

```
type obj = {
    name: string;
}

type mask = {
    o: obj;
}

// Approach 1
const o1 = {
    name: "raj",
    age: 24
}
const t1: mask = {
    o: o1
}


// Approach 2
const t2: mask = {
    o: {
        name: "raj",
        age: 24
    }
}
```

What's the difference in Approach 1/2? Why approach 2 is failing with `Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'obj'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'obj'.` error but not Approach 1?

Can someone help me to understand the Typescript validation rules?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour called `[excess-property-checks][1]`

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error:

In first example you did not receive an error because U use variable reference instead of literal.

Btw, by convention,  your types should be capitalized.

`type Obj = {name: string}`

instead of

`type obj = {name: string}`

It is much easier to read.

Btw, I believe your question is dublicate, so feel free to flag it